# Architecture logstash configuration file in ElasticStack

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-file

Hi guys i need ur idea in best ways in architecturing logstash configuration file. I have 3 environment sit, uat and prod and few host such as mq and webfitas. Each environment and host have few logs such as access.log, server.log and eai_new.log for (sit,uat and prod). In mq host i got server.log, mq.log and webfitas host i got fitas,log. Need ur advice how to architecture this in logstash.conf. i know the format of logstash.conf but not sure whether each environment and logs i should create a seoerate index. i will display it in charts later on in kibana. need your adivce guys

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly!

Comment: hi i am new to logstash and read many articles but still not get what i wanted. that is why i cam up with such question. if u have any info do share please